# How do I import editable copies of an existing "child-node" into a "parent-node"?

Tags: entities, nodes

**Here's what I need:**
I want to be able to import content of selected existing nodes (let's call them child-nodes) into a new node (let's call it parent-node), and I want to be able to edit the child-nodes inside the parent-node without changing the original child-node. E.g. automatically create a clone or revision of child-node. I need to be able to edit the complete child-node, not just a specific field.

**Here's what I have done:**
I have set up the ability to import the selected child-nodes into the parent-node using Entity Reference, and I have set up the ability to clone the child-nodes from the parent-node. The problem I have run into is that when I clone the child-node from the parent-node, the parent-node still refers to the original child-node instead of the clone.

Is there any way to resolve this, perhaps by using rules? or should I consider a different approach?